# Google Map v3 Chrome Bug: Clicking on map prevents mouseover events of iframe elements

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, mouseover

On this page http://gmap-sample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gmap.html

If you click on the map / marker or drag the map. Then unless you click outside the map somewhere, the mouseover event of anchor inside iframe will not work, even the cursor doesn't change it's style.

This issue doesn't happen with anchors present on page itself.

It happenes only in Chrome, not in IE or Firefox.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Chrome, not a bug in Google Maps. Transferring focus to the map (by clicking/dragging map/marker) removes focus from the parent window.  You could add some JS on mouseout of the map object which returns focus to the parent window.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried my suggestion myself but couldn't get it to do anything, even giving focus to the iframe itself prevented it doing anything.

Comment: @duncan I tried things like triggering click event on different elements outside map, but user has to **manually** click outside which is not useful.